# java: maps zoo, what to choose

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable, linkedhashmap

I'm pretty new to the Java World (since I'm writing primary in C/C++). I'm using maps in my apps.
Since `java.util.Map` is abstract I need to instantiate it's implementation. Usually I use `HashMap` like:

```
Map<String, MyClass> x = new HashMap<>();
```

But in java docs I found many other implementations, like `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, `HashTable`, etc. I want to know if I can continue blindly using of the `HashMap` or there are any **important** differences between those `Map` implementations.

The brief list of points-to-know will be ok.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the javadoc for those classes?

Comment: So, there's this company called Google...

Comment: @OpenSauce There are too much to read. I'll read it anyway, but for now I need a quick answer like a brief list of differences.

Comment: @Isaac So why you're registered here? Doesn't google help you?

Comment: @maverik, not always, unfortunately.

Comment: I have to downvote, just for this comment `There are too much to read. I'll read it anyway, but for now I need a quick answer like a brief list of difference`.

Comment: @Isaac I personally trust to SO more than other boards worldwide (I don't mentioned here the official docs and official communities, just a programming boards)

Comment: @maverik many Google results do, actually, end up here...

Comment: @Isaac sure. If it is a duplicate then it's my fault. Perception: official docs is a **must read** for all who uses the language. But once again, I'm not a Java programmer, I just need to rewrite a small piece of code. And do it quickly. I don't want to do it blindly but doesn't have enough time right know to read and (it is more important) to **understand** what I read in the official docs. I'm sorry if this makes your sad.

Comment: @maverik, note that my comment was written *before* you explained this situation of yours. From the initial looks of it, it was seen as if you're too lazy to do some research. No offence meant, clearly. Cheers

Comment: @Isaac sure, np and I'm sorry for my unclear explanation and question. I just need to solve the problem right now. Later I'll read the docs and can change something according to my needs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Never bother with `Hashtable`, it's a relic from Java 1.0;
- `HashMap` is the universal default due to O(1) lookup and reliance only on `equals` and `hashCode`, guaranteed to be implemented for all Java objects;
- `TreeMap` gives you sorted iteration over the map entries (plus a lot more—see `NavigableMap`), but requires a comparison strategy and has slower insertion and lookup – O(logN) – than `HashMap`;
- `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion/access order when iterating over the entries.

`SortedMap` implementations offer some great features, like `headMap` and `tailMap`. `NavigableMap` implementations offer even more features with terrific performance for operations that assume sorted keys.

Further out there are `java.util.concurrent` map implementations, like `ConcurrentHashMap`, which offer great concurrent performance and atomic get/put operations.

Comment: Another thing about TreeMap, it implements SortedMap

Comment: Thank you and all others. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: `HashMap` lookup is not `O(1)` - this heavily depends on the hash function and is in worst case `O(n)`. See the for loop in the sources of `get` - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/a42d6999734b/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: @SpaceTrucker It also sports a rehashing function that is applied to object's own `hashCode`, which mitigates these issues to a great extent.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it doesn't change the fact that complexity is not O(1).

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov This wasn't supposed to be an in-depth analysis of the behavior, but a quick glance. `TreeMap` is not O(logN), either.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what is the complexity of `TreeMap`? javadoc and wikipedia says it's O(logN).

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov It's O(logN) provided that the comparison function is O(1). There will always be such real-life complications if you want to delve into it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hm, right. But it's valid only if comparison function need to iterate over the same map to compare 2 objects. If it's not the case than complexity O(logN) even if each comparison takes forever.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Well, iterating over the same map would be one way to get there, but not nearly the only one; it's just a matter of your imagination. Furthermore, the whole big-O measure can be rendered useless in practice, where constant factors matter as well. And so on, and so on... the matryoshka of real-life performance has many layers.

Answer (score 2):

- `HashMap` use it almost all the time. Note that your object need have proper implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Does not save insertion order.
- `HashTable` don't use it never.
- `LinkedHashMap` the same as `HashMap` but saves insertion order. Large overhead.
- `TreeMap` support natural ordering. But insertion works in O(logn).

Answer (score 2):

- [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is the thread safe version of [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you shouldn't use it anymore. instead you should use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which is a new implementation of a thread safe map
- [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is mostly use when you want to sort your keys, it implements the [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface. The put/get performance is O(logn).
- [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) is used if you need a thread safe [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)
- [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is used when you want to iterate on keys in the insertion order

I mostly use `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` if I need it to be thread safe

Answer (score 1):

There of course are important differences between each of these maps.  It depends purely on what you are trying to do.  If you recall a `HashMap` becomes pretty useless (see inefficient) when you have a poor hashing function in place.  The `LinkedHashMap` is a `HashMap` that is backed by a doubly linked list, so you can iterate over it.  You would eat the overhead that is associated with a linked list of course.  `TreeMap`  keeps elements in order, so you will eat that overhead.  `HashTable` is a synchronized collection, that is generally avoided.

Answer (score 0):

> are any important differences between those Map implementations

Yes there are some major differences to consider when choosing an implementation of `Map`.

- **Concurrency**
  Will you be manipulating this map [across threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)?
- **NULLs**
  Do you want to accept, or reject, [NULL pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer) as key and/or value?
- **Sorting**
  Do you want map entries put in some order, such as sorted order or original-insertion order? Do you want support for the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html)/[`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interfaces?
- **Not Modifiable**
  Do you want a map to be frozen, refusing to accept or remove entries?
- **Identity**
  Do want to compare keys based on [reference-equality or object-equality](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Comparing_Objects)?
- **Efficiency**
  Do you want to take advantage of the very fast performance and very little memory used when your key is an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)?
- **Literals**
  Do you want the convenience of declaring *and* populating a map in a single line of code?
- **Legacy**
  Do you want to avoid using a [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) map, created before the modern [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework)?

Here is a graphic table I made comparing the features of each of the ten `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11.

[image: Table comparing the features of the ten implementations of <code>Map</code> bundled with Java 11.]